# Does it make sense to memoize large array operations in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have a component:

```
export const MyComponent = ({largeArray}) => {
    const arrayINeed = largeArray.sort()
}
```

From what I understand, `largeArray.sort()` will be called every time `MyComponent` re-renders, if `largeArray` is huge, doesn't that raise some degree of performance concerns?

Is it better in this case to memoize the result like this?:

```
export const MyComponent = ({largeArray}) => {
    const sortedArray = useMemo(() => largeArray.sort(), [largeArray])
}
```

Comment: in most of cases - yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It's also important to recognize that you are mutating the array passed in props by calling its [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method. Instead, spread the array into a new array and sort the new array:

```js
import {useMemo} from 'react';

export const MyComponent = ({largeArray}) => {
  const sortedArray = useMemo(() => [...largeArray].sort(), [largeArray]);
}
```

Comment: Be careful to make sure your parent component isn't updating the reference for largeArray every time it renders, otherwise this memo won't do anything but add overhead.